# Bad form to return None in __init__ in python

Tags: python, class, coding-style, initialization

I was tinkering around with some classes and I came upon a situation where I wanted to cut off `__init__` before it got a chance to do anything more. To do so, I simply put a null `return` statement at the end of the block I wanted to cut off at. For example:

```
class Example(object):
    def __init__(self):
        #lots and lots of code
        if so_and_so:
            return
```

Is it bad form to return inside `__init__`, even if it's just under this circumstance?

Comment: Likely you need to use `__new__` instead of `__init__`. `__init__` isn't a constructor, it's initializer

Comment: Agree, you should use __new__ if you want a return value

Comment: But OP isn't trying to return a non-None value.  OP just wants to break early.  No problem with a `return` there...

Comment: you can't return anything from __init__(), just use condition inside it if match do the initialization else do nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For any function, not only `__init__`, using plain `return` is equivalent to returning `None`, and if you don't use `return` in a function, `None` is implicitly returned anyway.

Therefor, it is perfectly fine to use `return` inside `__init__`.

(The exception to the rule above is generator functions, inside which you may only use `return` and not `return None`, so these are not equivalent inside generator functions).

Returning in the middle of `__init__` will simply cut off object's *initialization*. It will not prevent the object from being created, nor interrupt program's flow in any way.

Comment: As I understand he/she asks if it's possible to abort object creation. This should be done outside `__init__` which is intended for object initialization, not object creation

Comment: @user3159253, ok, thanks. I added a comment clarifying what my answer is referring to

Comment: I don't think you can return anything from __init__()

Comment: @sjcipher correct, you may not return anything except for `None` from `__init__`. In my answer, I did not claim you can. However, both `return` and `return None` are valid. (please re-consider the downvote...)

Answer (score 3):

How long is a piece of string? If you don't need to initialize any further, then there's no point in continuing. Since `None` is returned implicitly at the end anyway (and in fact should be the *only* thing ever returned by `__init__()`), returning it early if initialization has been completed is fine.

OTOH, if you need to *abort* initialization then you should raise an exception instead.